# Ignite Discovery worker blocked error when client node attempts to connect

Tags: java, kubernetes, ignite

We have deployed an Ignite 2.11.1 cluster in Kubernetes.  When a client node attempts to join the grid, we are getting the tcp-disco-msg-worker blocked below.

We have used the same configuration successfully with another deployment so we are not certain why we are getting this error. The only change is that in the deployment that is failing we have added resource limits to the configuration.

```
[20:07:24,201][SEVERE][tcp-disco-msg-worker-[crd]-#2-#48][G] Blocked system-critical thread has been detected. This can lead to cluster-wide undefined behaviour [workerName=db-checkpoint-thread, threadName=db-checkpoint-thread-#78, blockedFor=4562s]
[20:07:24] Possible failure suppressed accordingly to a configured handler [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, err=class o.a.i.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=db-checkpoint-thread, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1657047082073]]]
[20:07:27,073][SEVERE][tcp-disco-msg-worker-[crd]-#2-#48][G] Blocked system-critical thread has been detected. This can lead to cluster-wide undefined behaviour [workerName=sys-stripe-0, threadName=sys-stripe-0-#1, blockedFor=4072s]

Thread [name="qtp2015455415-61", id=61, state=TIMED_WAITING, blockCnt=1, waitCnt=702]
    Lock [object=java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@78322a4, ownerName=null, ownerId=-1]
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.BlockingArrayQueue.poll(BlockingArrayQueue.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.idleJobPoll(QueuedThreadPool.java:973)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1023)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 
Thread [name="qtp2015455415-60", id=60, state=RUNNABLE, blockCnt=3, waitCnt=679]
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
        - locked sun.nio.ch.Util$3@7a7b4390
        - locked java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet@220c68db
        - locked sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@4f569077
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:101)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.nioSelect(ManagedSelector.java:183)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.select(ManagedSelector.java:190)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.select(ManagedSelector.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:543)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produceTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:360)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:184)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:383)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:882)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1036)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 
Thread [name="qtp2015455415-59", id=59, state=TIMED_WAITING, blockCnt=1, waitCnt=684]
    Lock [object=java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@78322a4, ownerName=null, ownerId=-1]
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.BlockingArrayQueue.poll(BlockingArrayQueue.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.idleJobPoll(QueuedThreadPool.java:973)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1023)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 
Thread [name="qtp2015455415-58", id=58, state=TIMED_WAITING, blockCnt=1, waitCnt=688]
    Lock [object=java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@78322a4, ownerName=null, ownerId=-1]
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.BlockingArrayQueue.poll(BlockingArrayQueue.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.idleJobPoll(QueuedThreadPool.java:973)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1023)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Client side errors:

```
06-Jul-2022 15:16:04.772 INFO [exchange-worker-#45%igniteClientInstance%] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError]. The
following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1427)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1415)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1254)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1215)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3219)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
06-Jul-2022 15:16:43.252 INFO [page-lock-tracker-timeout] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persi
stence.diagnostic.pagelocktracker.SharedPageLockTracker$State]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.diagnostic.pagelocktracker.SharedPageLockTracker$State]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1427)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1415)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1254)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1215)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.diagnostic.pagelocktracker.SharedPageLockTracker.getThreadOperationState(SharedPageLockTracker.java:285)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.diagnostic.pagelocktracker.SharedPageLockTracker.hangThreads(SharedPageLockTracker.java:301)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.diagnostic.pagelocktracker.SharedPageLockTracker.access$200(SharedPageLockTracker.java:53)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.diagnostic.pagelocktracker.SharedPageLockTracker$TimeOutWorker.iteration(SharedPageLockTracker.java:359)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.CycleThread.run(CycleThread.java:49)
06-Jul-2022 15:25:42.469 INFO [tcp-comm-worker-#1%igniteClientInstance%-#28%igniteClientInstance%] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [java.lan
g.OutOfMemoryError]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1427)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1415)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1254)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1215)
                at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.CommunicationWorker.body(CommunicationWorker.java:194)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
                at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$6.body(TcpCommuicationSpi.java:928)
                at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:58)
```

Comment: Can you attach the full thread dump, in particular what's happening to the reported sys-stripe-0-#1 and db-checkpoint-thread ?

Comment: Hey Richard, is the issue fixed ?

Comment: @MahipalReddy This specific problem seemed to be related to networking issues and not Ignite itself.